# Getting the ConnectionProvider from a SessionFactory

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, connection

To do some custom (blackboxed) SQL actions, i need to have an IDBConnection instance to a database that we already regularly access via NHibernate.

I do not want to deploy separate database configurations (one native, one nhibernate), but instead want NHibernate to give me direct access to the one already configured.

I see that the ISession interface has a connection property, and i could create a dummy session, but i´d rather use a connection that is completely independent from any session created.

So I wondered if there is any chance to get the the IConnectionProvider instance that is used by a session factory to provide the connections for the sessions created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution relies on an implementation detail of NHibernate. It has worked in all instances where I used it, but this may not be true after upgrading NHibernate.

Assuming you have our field `ISessionFactory _sessionFactory` you can use the following cast to get to the connection provider. Even though the documentation says the interface `ISessionFactoryImplementor` is for communication between the session factory and other parts of NHibernate, it is public.

```
(_sessionFactory as NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor).ConnectionProvider
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine with opening a session just to get the connection. The only gotcha that I could think of is the session might be GCed unexpectedly if not stored somewhere.

If you want the session provider, then you will need access to the Configuration object:

```
public IConnectionProvider GetProvider(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(cfg.GetProperty(Environment.ConnectionProvider));
    return (IConnectionProvider) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Comment: Thx, but that code gives me a new (unconfigured) instance of the same type, it would not give me the configured provider instance...